# How to re-enable "Automatically add files to VCS" in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

The first time I created a file in PHPStorm I accidentally clicked "Don't automatically add this file to my VCS" (that's a paraphrase of course) and it's driving me nuts that I have to keep doing this manually.  I can find instructions on how to do this manually but I'm not sure how to have it happen automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to [`Settings | Version Control | Confirmation`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/confirmation.html?search=confirm) and here in area `When files are created` set option `Add Silently`. That's it !